# Can someone help me with a powershell script that will add users to groups based Their OU?

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I am trying to create a script to add people to groups and i would like something like an IF statement that will automatically add our employees to their VLAN group if they are in a certain OU. Lets say our employees are in OU = test and they will be added to the group "Test VLAN" 
I would like to add this to my script that checks which OU they're in and adds them to a specific VLAN group.

Thanks

Comment: so ... what have you tried? have you looked at `get-help *search*`, for instance?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Split this into different parts and you will be able to find how to do it: 1. Find all users in an OU with PowerShell, 2. Add users to a group with PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, no activedirectory module needed.

You would need to adjust the LDAP filter to your liking. Currently it does it for all user objects with the Title field populated

```
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")

# LDAP search filter, this gets all users with the title field populated
$searchFilter = "(&(objectclass=user)(title=*))"

# Hash mapping between group name and OU
$mapping = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Test VLAN";         Value = "OU=Test,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Test VLAN 2";       Value = "OU=Test2,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "Test VLAN 123123";  Value = "OU=Test123123,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com"}
)

# Get all users in Active Directory
$directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"")
$directorySearcher.Filter = $searchFilter
$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname")
$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname")
$users = $directorySearcher.FindAll()

$domainName = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().Name
$principalContext = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new("Domain",$domainName)

# Loop through users and add them to group
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userPrincipal = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($principalContext, $user.Properties.samaccountname)
    if ($userPrincipal) {
        $vlanGroup = $mapping.Where({$user.Properties.distinguishedname.EndsWith($_.Value)})
        if ($vlanGroup) {
            $groupPrincipal = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($principalContext, $vlanGroup.Name)
            if ($userPrincipal.IsMemberOf($groupPrincipal)) {
                Write-Verbose "User '$($user.Properties.samaccountname)' is already memberof '$($vlanGroup)'"
            }
            else {
                $groupPrincipal.Members.Add($userPrincipal)
                $groupPrincipal.Save()
                Write-Verbose "Added user '$($user.Properties.samaccountname)' to group '$($vlanGroup)'"
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Verbose "No VLAN mapping found for user '$($user.Properties.samaccountname)'"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose "Unable to find userprincipal for '$($user.Properties.samaccountname)'"
    }
    Clear-Variable 'userPrincipal', 'vlanGroup', 'groupPrincipal' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```